# Matrix inverse of block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} T & l \\l^*& S \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

Consider the special block matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} T & l \\l^*& S \end{pmatrix},$$ where we assume that each entry is invertible and $l$ and $l^*$ denote a scalar (and its complex conjugate) times the identity, whereas $T$ and $S$ are full matrices of equal size.

Is there a simple formula for the matrix inverse $A^{-1}?$ I am aware there are general formulas for block matrix inverses, but I thought in this case, things should simplify?

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I don't think that there is any especially simple solution to this problem - than what you would get by using the standard block inversion lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion). The final form will be a little cleaner - with nice looking Schur complements, but computationally there is no major speedup / simplification to be obtained (afaik).

Comment: well, yes, I am asking for a simplified final form.

Comment: Then maybe you can try developing it a bit and say where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the block-inversion formula linked in the comments, we have
$$
\pmatrix{\mathbf{A}^{-1}+\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} & -\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1} \\ -(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} & (\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B})^{-1}} = \\
\pmatrix{T^{-1}+|l|^2T^{-1}(S-|l|^2T^{-1})^{-1}T^{-1} & 
-l\,T^{-1}(S-|l|^2 T^{-1})^{-1} \\ 
-l^*(S-|l|^2 T^{-1})^{-1}T^{-1} & (S-|l|^2T^{-1})^{-1}} = \\
\pmatrix{T^{-1}[1+|l|^2(TS-|l|^2)^{-1}] & 
-l\,(ST-|l|^2 )^{-1} \\ 
-l^*(TS-|l|^2 )^{-1} & T(ST-|l|^2)^{-1}} 
$$